# When you open a PNG in Sublime, what encoding does it show and how do you convert it?

Tags: python, png, sublimetext2, decode, sublimetext

I'm creating a Python script which does a task and then produces output along with a PNG file. When I put the PNG file into Sublime text.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It is just hex. It has a one to one relationship with binary. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexadecimal That IS your PNG file :)

Comment: Thanks Elimirks. So I need a python module that converts hex into an image?

Comment: Can you show some of the code which produces the PNG?

Comment: Hi Kyle, this is the full code that produces the PNG:

8950 4e47 0d0a 1a0a 0000 000d 4948 4452
0000 0020 0000 0020 0806 0000 0073 7a7a
f400 0000 0662 4b47 4400 0000 0000 00f9
43bb 7f00 0000 096f 4646 7300 0000 0000
0000 e000 8454 4522 0000 0009 7048 5973
0000 0b13 0000 0b13 0100 9a9c 1800 0000
3849 4441 5458 c3ed d541 0a00 2008 0041
ffff e97a 8187 0829 7406 bc2f 081a 01f0
b975 394d 024e 0928 0dc8 f62d 40c0 9c00
77e0 49c0 e86f 0894 db16 5a41 dbbd c804
f700 0000 0049 454e 44ae 4260 82

Comment: Your question is rather unclear. So, what task have you done? Have you made a picture,and want to _save_ as a png? A little bit more context would be helpful.

Comment: I have a PNG file and I want to produce a txt file output (which I've done) and I want to produce a photo.PNG file as well as the txt file. So I've put the PNG file into sublime and saw all the hex listed above. I want to include that hex in the script and output it to a PNG file. I hope this makes sense.

Comment: Ah, I'll be changing my answer up a bit.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The "encoding" you're seeing in Sublime is just the hexadecimal representation of the PNG (also called a [hexdump](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hex_dump)).

Sublime, by default, shows the hex dump of binary files.

[image: sublime hex]

Bytes 1-3 (byte 0 is 89) are ascii `'PNG'`.

- `50` → `P`
- `4e` → `N`
- `47` → `G`

Consult an [ascii table](http://web.cs.mun.ca/~michael/c/ascii-table.html) to see for yourself.

If you open the file in vim, you get garbeldy-gook binary mess but you can at least see the *file magic* denoting this as a PNG:

[image: vim binary]

It's the same image though. You just need to open it with an image viewer (or your browser).

[image: cat]

If you're wanting to create the hexdump of this image, just read it in, convert it with binascii, and voila!

```
import binascii
ff = open("cat.png", "rb")
data = ff.read()
ff.close()

txt = binascii.hexlify(data)

fw = open("cat.txt", "w")
fw.write(txt)
fw.close()
```

If you have a full hex dump (no spaces though), you can convert back:

```
import binascii

ff = open("cat.txt", "r")
txt = ff.read()
ff.close()

image = binascii.unhexlify(txt)
```

If you do have spaces (as above with Sublime), just get rid of all the whitespace while you're at it.

```
import binascii

ff = open("cat.txt", "r")
txt = ff.read()
ff.close()

# Split on space, join back with no separator
txt = "".join(txt.split()) 

image = binascii.unhexlify(txt)
```

Comment: Thanks Kyle, I understand that but how do I use python to save that hex as a PNG? I was looking at the PIL module but can't see much on hex to images. EDIT: Perfect. Thanks.

Comment: You want to go hex -> binary?

Comment: Well I was just looking to convert that hex into a png file. I think I can do it with the code you provided me with. I'm going to give it a try now :)